# Как «натащить» box-shadow на border?

Tags: z-index, html, css

Привет, есть такая ситуация:

[image]

Хочу чтобы квадрат как бы "увеличивался" при ховере, но какой-то остаточный бордер мешается, помогите найти варианты. Вот фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/sax48/1/
Корректное отображение только у ячейки с номером 16.

P.S> Потестил... некорректное отображение только у -webkit.

Opera12.16(Presto), FF - отображает как нужно, IE9 - не отображает совсем (приемлемо) -> подскажите что с вебкитом?

Comment: position: absolute;
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/sax48/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.flat__grid td:hover {
    position: absolute; /*вот тут*/
    z-index: 10;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо господин eicto, всё работает. Но не могу понять логику, почему это работает??? да и при ховере текст в немного съезжает, вниз и\или всторону, я как понимаю это из за бордера?

Comment: ну мне скорее удивительно, что с relative хоть где-то работает, чтобы не съезжало пишите `border: 0 solid #ccc;`